# InvalidMutabilityExceptionInvalidMutabilityException on common test with Ktor

Tags: kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-multiplatform

I have a multiplatform library to do few APIs calls with Ktor (2.0.0-beta-1)

```
class DiscoveryServicesImpl(private val client: HttpClient) : DiscoveryServices {
    override suspend fun getServers(domain: String): DAAServers {
        return client.get(Servers.Domain(domain = domain)).body()
    }
}

// Where client is created with specific engine (OkHttp for Android and Darwin for iOS)
```

This code works as expected (implemented in both Android and iOS apps)

To secure this code, I've added a unit test to verify that the url is well builded.

```
@Test
fun getServersSuccessful() {
    runBlocking {
        var _request: HttpRequestData? = null

        //Given
        val mockEngine = MockEngine {
            _request = it
        }
        val discoveryApiMock = DiscoveryApi(mockEngine)
        val service = DiscoveryServicesImpl(discoveryApiMock.client)

        //When
        val servers: DAAServers = service.getServers(domain)

        //Then
        assertEquals("https://****/$domain", _request!!.url.toString())
    }

}
```

But when a run this test I got an error (for iOS test only) :

```
> Task :api:discovery:iosTest

***.discovery.DiscoveryServicesImplTest.getServersSuccessful FAILED
    kotlin.native.concurrent.InvalidMutabilityException at /Users/teamcity1/teamcity_work/6326934d18cfe24e/kotlin/kotlin-native/runtime/src/main/kotlin/kotlin/Throwable.kt:24



kotlin.native.concurrent.InvalidMutabilityException: mutation attempt of frozen kotlin.native.internal.Ref@15cb7c8
kotlin.native.concurrent.InvalidMutabilityException: mutation attempt of frozen kotlin.native.internal.Ref@15cb7c8
    at kotlin.Throwable#<init>(/Users/teamcity1/teamcity_work/6326934d18cfe24e/kotlin/kotlin-native/runtime/src/main/kotlin/kotlin/Throwable.kt:24)
    at kotlin.Exception#<init>(/Users/teamcity1/teamcity_work/6326934d18cfe24e/kotlin/kotlin-native/runtime/src/main/kotlin/kotlin/Exceptions.kt:23)
    at kotlin.RuntimeException#<init>(/Users/teamcity1/teamcity_work/6326934d18cfe24e/kotlin/kotlin-native/runtime/src/main/kotlin/kotlin/Exceptions.kt:34)
    at kotlin.native.concurrent.InvalidMutabilityException#<init>(/Users/teamcity1/teamcity_work/6326934d18cfe24e/kotlin/kotlin-native/runtime/src/main/kotlin/kotlin/native/concurrent/Freezing.kt:24)
    at <global>.ThrowInvalidMutabilityException(/Users/teamcity1/teamcity_work/6326934d18cfe24e/kotlin/kotlin-native/runtime/src/main/kotlin/kotlin/native/concurrent/Internal.kt:109)
    at <global>.MutationCheck(Unknown Source)
    at kotlin.native.internal.Ref#<set-element>(/Users/teamcity1/teamcity_work/6326934d18cfe24e/kotlin/kotlin-native/runtime/src/main/kotlin/kotlin/native/internal/Ref.kt:12)
```

It's happening only on the ios target

To fix this, I've added this code pretty much everywhere (commonMain, commonTest, iosMain, iosTest) but it doesn't change anything

```
implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.0-native-mt") {
    version {
        strictly("1.6.0-native-mt")
    }
}
```

Below, my gradles files :

```
kotlin {
    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(Ktor.clientCore)
                implementation(Ktor.clientResources)
                implementation(Ktor.contentNegotiation)
                implementation(Ktor.clientJson)
                implementation(Ktor.clientLogging)
                implementation(Ktor.clientAuth)
                implementation(Koin.koinMultiplatform)
                implementation(project(":serialization"))
                implementation(project(":transverse:log"))

                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.0-native-mt") {
                    version {
                        strictly("1.6.0-native-mt")
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(Ktor.clientMock)
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:1.6.0-native-mt") {
                    version {
                        strictly("1.6.0-native-mt")
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        val iosMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(Ktor.clientDarwin)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the latest version of ktor and coroutines, you'll probably want to use the new memory model, and just the `1.6.0` kotlinx.coroutines rather than the native-mt version.

https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2021/08/try-the-new-kotlin-native-memory-manager-development-preview/

https://github.com/touchlab/KaMPKit/blob/main/gradle.properties#L26

Most library dev from Jetbrains will likely focus on the new memory model from now on, so unless there are specific near term concerns on moving, I would do that.

Comment: Tanks !
I've tried this yesterday and seems to not york (enable preview in build.gradle instead of seetings.gradle https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/kotlin-native/NEW_MM.md). I tried today and it's work. Might be to tired.
Thanks again :)